# nodejs Is possible to use knex.raw with stream?

Tags: node.js, stream, knex.js

I looked for info about using knex.raw with stream: https://knexjs.org/?spm=a2c6h.24755359.0.0.34556828cZIXxW#Interfaces-Streams
but I didn't find a specific example using raw.

I wrote this code I thougth could work, but is not working.

```
rpta="select id, info from students"
const query = await db.raw(rpta).stream();

query.on('data', ({key, value}) => {
            console.log(value)
            console.log("data");
        });
query.on('end', () => {
            console.log("end");
        });
```

I'm sure the query returns data, but is not even printing "end" or "data". Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Knex's documentation of their stream interface seems only to document (ie implement) the `.pipe()` approach to streaming, rather than the continuously flowing `.on("data")` method. Does it work when you remove the `await` and pipe the result to a middleware, according to the documentation?

Comment: I didn't solve this, but I use pg and ('pg-query-stream')